# Mac freezes after entering login password

Tags: mac, password, performance

My Mac starts up normally, but when I enter my password on the login screen, it freezes with a spinning beachball.

I am unable to access it due to this problem. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: MacBook model?  macOS version?  Have you tried booting into safe mode (hold Shift while booting)?  Have you tried booting into Recovery?

Comment: MacBook Pro mid 2012 with OS Sierra yes I tried the recovery mode it works, I checked my hard drive with the S.O.S everything is fine but when I want to install the OS it failed

Comment: What was the error message?  As a test, get an external USB flash drive and install macOS there.  If it works, your drive is in the process of failing, if it fails again, there may be an issue with the hardware (i.e. logic board)

Comment: I think about doing that but I don’t have a USB flash drive and I did a hard drive S.O.S test in recovery mode it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting your Mac in safe mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after pressing the power button. If that works, you can at least back up your files and we can try to find a solution from there.

You can find more details on safe mode in the Apple support article, [Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201262).

Comment: I tried the safe mode but same problem